# Have I Implemented the catch block correcly in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import shutil

def copyDirectory(src, dest):

    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dest)
    except IOError as why:
        print (why.strerror + ": "  + src)



source="C:/Users/Nexusfactor/Desktop/Copy"
destination="C:/Users/Nexusfactor/Desktop/Destination"

copyDirectory(source, destination)
```

I've written a script that copies a directory to a destination. Should the source directory not exist then it will print a message saying so.

Question:

Have I done anything in my script that is considered bad practice when trying and catching errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is basically fine, but are you sure you want to silence the error?

If someone were to use your `copyDirectory()` function to copy a directory, and then went on to do other stuff, his program will continue to run even though the directory copying failed. It might even raise an other error later on from elsewhere due to this, and it might be harder to trace by then.

Why not just raise an error? Let everyone handle their own failures of copying a directory, as it's usually an essential part of your program that the copying was a success.

Comment: AH, Could you help me correct my code, to illustrate what you're saying?

Comment: @Nexusfactor Why define a `copyDirectory()` in the first place, why not use `shutil.copytree()` directly?

Comment: I could, but, I learned how to write functions in Python and saw few examples where they used a function, but I could. No real reason, other than, I wanted to,

Comment: @Nexusfactor Functions are insanely useful and you should totally learn how to use them, but this function will cause more bad than good. All your function seems to do is call `shutil.copytree()` and silence the error if the copying failed. Usually it's vital that the copying succeeded, so you're just causing problems with this by not ending the program on a failure to copy a directory.

Comment: AH! much appreciated. How then would I not silence the error. I'm new to python, so any help is appreciated. If you could, can you correct my code in your answer?

Comment: @Nexusfactor Don't do anything, just use `shutil.copytree()` wherever you'd use your `copyDirectory()`.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated

Comment: Just for my understanding, you mean, call it directly without the try/catch?

Comment: @Nexusfactor Yes. If you need to handle it in one place, do so right there, but you don't need a function for it.

Comment: I'm a little confused when you say "silence the error", because I issue a message saying that the directory wasn't found. Forgive me, but could you provide a little more explanation.

Comment: @Nexusfactor By "silencing" I meant that you're letting the program's execution continue normally. If you were not to handle the error, the program's execution would end immediately. Now the program will continue to run and unexpected behaviour **will** arrive. The error will be printed anyways, even if you don't use `try`/`except`.

Comment: @Nexusfactor Let's put it this way: Why do you think you need a function for this, what's the purpose of the function? Why do you need to prevent the program from stopping?

Comment: Honestly, there is no real reason why I need  to prevent it from stopping. You're correct. Thanks for your explanation, much appreciated. As for the function part, it's totally unnecessary, I agree.

Comment: Is there a way then, to have a more readable message for the user, instead of the messy traceback error that I get when I run it in the shell.

Comment: @Nexusfactor Yes, use a `try`/`except` in your main function. Just make sure to restart or exit the program/while loop/etc